# New batteries make loud pop sounds after charging?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger, charging

I bought a new charger and new batterie, nitecore i2 (two bays), and AmazonBasics AAA. I charged in pairs but nearly everytime i do so, one of the batteries is popping during or right after the charge.  When i charge single, no popping. When i charge in pairs, there is popping. Which is faulty, and what should i return?

Comment: Does it also growl in the night? Birds won't fly overhead?

Comment: I would not keep using it. Very early protected li-ion cells had almost spring or perhaps tention loaded resettable fuses which mechanically disconnected the cell in case of over voltage or over current. Highly unlikely though that would be it and you would hear it operate.

Comment: not keep using the battery or the charger?

Answer (score 2):

If the battery is making a noise, it's probably damaged.

Whether it was badly made or the charger damaged it is hard to tell, but I would place a small bet on it being the battery. The Nitecore charging stations (at least on the larger 4-bay ones) have independent charging circuits.

Comment: it 2 bay, it says it has Active distribution thing. The amazon batteries have "vents" on the positive tip end, i think thats where the pops come from.

Comment: Right, but we don't know if the batteries were bad from the factory or if the charger damaged the batteries due to either a defect in the charger or incompatibility with the charger. You can read the manual to make sure the charger is compatible and then try more batteries in the bay (to see if the problem follows the bay). Batteries that vent should not be reused.